# AngularJS :can not take on consideration when calling ng-click in the view to use it in the controller

Tags: angularjs

could anyone help me ? because I'm new on AngularJS and I didn't understand the logic of ng-click in this case which is that when I click on the link which contains in its tag the ng-click , it doesn't work and there is no any responce from the controller to do a specific treatment.

Here is my code

**view.html:**

```
<div class="tile-config dropdown">
   <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="" class="tooltips tile-menu" title="" data-original-title="Options"></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-right"> 
        <li><a href="" ng-click="editCustomer(customer.Id)">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="deleteCustomer(customer.Id)">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

controller.js:

```
app.controller('CustomerListCtrl', ['$scope','GetCustomersFactory', '$location',
        function ($scope, GetCustomersFactory, $location) {

                $scope.editCustomer = function (customerId) {
                  $location.path('/customer-edit/' + customerId);   
                }


                  $scope.deleteCustomer = function () {
                      //DeleteCustomerFactory.remove({ id: customerId });
                      $location.path('/customers');
                  };


                    $scope.createNewCustomer = function () {
                    $location.path('/customer-add');
                  };

                  $scope.customers = GetCustomersFactory.query();
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your `href`

```
<a ng-click="editCustomer(customer.Id)">Edit</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a console.log(customerId) into your   $scope.editCustomer method to be sure that the method is executed when you click on the link.
Did you bounded the controller to the view?

Comment: there is a result n the console

Comment: if there is a result. check your route to confirm that  it is properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the controller is not being called on the view.

you should either add it to the route configuration, or add it directly on the view as `ng-controller="CustomerListCtrl"`